# Toggling between term-char-mode and term-line-mode

Tags: multi-term

How do I bind a key sequence to toggle between term-char-mode and term-line-mode (using multi-term)?

There doesn't seem to be a `term-char-minor-mode-map` and a `-line-` that could be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "H-j") 'term-line-mode)
(define-key term-mode-map (kbd "H-j") 'term-char-mode)
```